how to make enum values 64 bits in .idl file
Im working on WPF project with C++ and C#. I have written .idl file for communicating between these modules. I defined one enum like
typedef enum Samp{
    Samp1 =1,
    Samp2 =2,
    Samp3 =4,....
    Samp32=4294967296
}SampEnum;

each enum representing a number with only 1 bit set, now i need to add more enums, now it is taking 32 bit as default but i need to convert it to 64, how to change it. I tried these methods but all are giving compiler errors.
1st way is
i declared typedef for unsigned long long
typedef unsigned long long typeUll;
and tried to use this inside enum as
typedef enum Samp{
    Samp1 =typeUll(1),
    Samp2 =typeUll(2),
    ....
}SampEnum;

2nd way is  using @bit_bound, i found in some link to use @bit_bound(64) like this
@bit_bound(64)
bitmask MyBitMask
{
    @position(0) flag0,
    @position(1) flag1,
    @position(2) flag2,
    @position(3) flag3,
    ...
    @position(63) falg63
};

they mentioned like if we use @bit_bound this way, it will be converted to ---->
enum MyBitMask : uint64_t
{
    flag0 = 1 << 0,
    flag1 = 1 << 1,
    flag2 = 1 << 2,
    flag3 = 1 << 3,
    ....
    flag63 = 1<<63
};

For both im getting compiler errors. Can anyone help on this how to resolve this for supporting 64 bits in enum inside .idl files

Did you try use enum class?

No, we used typedef enum Samp{ samp1 =1, samp2=2, ... }SampEnum; like this only, it is a large code base so im trying a way to use same enum but need to support 64 bits values

enum [class] name : type is correct, at least for C++ (no idea what "idl" is, though). What errors are you getting?

Why use COM in the first place (at least I assume you mean COM, because that uses .idl files). I have tons of experience with COM and it would not be my first choice for C++/C# interop, C++/clr" will give you more control. With respect to 64 bit enums : idl normally has 16 bit enums, which you can grow to 32 bits with [v1_enum]  attribute, but there isn't a 64 bit option.

Also in the idl file use typedef enum SampEnum{ ... } SampEnum; (Don't use two different names)
